# I disabled my only Administrator account?

Tags: windows

I disabled my built in administrator and now i can't log in with the administrator account. Only a user account is left. What to do?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/70334/winxp-administrator-password-recovery

Comment: Technically not really identical, though I'll give you similar ;)  The other solution is the only one available when you can't remember the password, IIRC.  In this case, he/she may know the passwd but bungled up when disabling accounts. This can be easily fixed with Windows Repair provided the password is known.

Comment: If you want a meaningful answer, you need to provide meaningful details.

Answer (score 4):

It would be nice to have some details, like which OS you're running, but I'll make an assumption based on the tags.  Hopefully this applies to your version of windows.

You need to boot up with the install CD and choose "Repair"

Next get to the command prompt and type the following:

`net user administrator /active:yes`

Of course, if the username is not administrator, use the correct username.

Answer (score 1):

Boot the computer into safe mode (Hit F8 as the computer is booting) and login as administrator there. Go to your User accounts in your control panel and re-enable the administrator account.

Comment: I doubt no password applies here.

Comment: You're correct and I've edited to reflect the change

Comment: So, but now your answer doesn't make sense anymore. How to login with a disabled Administrator?

Comment: You can log into a disabled administrator account in safe mode.